# Search file system with Xcode Mac application

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, search

my uncle challenged me to make an application in which you can search the file system of a Mac. I've never actually had to do this yet in my programming experience, but I think it would be good to know as well. I have a search field, and a button that says search. Does anybody know how I can make that search the file system, and display the results? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should help: http://macdevcenter.com/pub/a/mac/2005/07/12/spotlight.html?page=1

Comment: @user354779: that doesn't really matter - the principle remains the same, i.e. use the Spotlight APIs.